# Maven Spring boot and Spring Cloud pom dependency not found

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-starter-parent

I find this difficult to identify all of sudden **CI/CD pipeline** broken due to the fact that Spring boot pom is not available anymore at the location.

When I ran the command `mvn clean install`, I see below two pom are misplaced/not available anymore, which was historically working for 3-4 years till now -

First one -

```
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom

Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom
```

And second -

```
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Brixton.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dependencies-Brixton.RELEASE.pom

Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Brixton.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dependencies-Brixton.RELEASE.pom
```

In the pom.xml I have mentioned below dependency -

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>
```

POM has mention of below repository -

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Any clue what is happening here ? Hope for the understanding.

Note: The project was built at the time Spring 1.3.3 version was released and we cannot change the version straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are missing the RELEASE repo

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-repo</id>
    <name>Spring Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    <snapshots>
       <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

As per [this](https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020) blog, one should be using the maven central for Spring dependencies. `https://repo.spring.io/release` can also be blocked in the future.

```
<repository>
    <id>maven-central</id>
    <name>Maven Centrail</name>
    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    <snapshots>
       <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Comment: Awesome, now it started fetching repos, don't know how it worked so far. Could you relate this to any recent changes to spring repo. Or better if you can guide me to right resources to understand snapshot/milestone/release repos please..

Comment: I would assume the impact is due to the sunset of bintray. https://status.bintray.com

Comment: What is the alternative  for for this plugin repo -

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
   <id>central</id>
   <name>bintray-plugins</name>
   <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>

Comment: Try https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 The maven central should have all the dependencies

Comment: I am still facing some issues. Created another thread for it. Please have a look when you get chance- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67364271/javax-persistence-and-hibernate-core-maven-dependency-not-working-with-spring-bo

Comment: All dependency started falling apart since the changes. I have posted the details another  thread shared above. It seems child module are not getting the dependencies from parent entirely like - persistence, hibernate-core, slf4j etc